# How to generate the socket emit events under API's calls

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I need the help/support/guidance regarding the Socket.io
On My server page i.e app.js, I initialized the Socket and it works fine. Now I want to call the emit function to some other page. But I did not get the event from another page because the event generated under connection.
I will share the pseudo code by which you can get some idea about app.js page

```
const io = require('socket.io');
  const server = io.listen(3003);
  const triggerEvent = (socket) => {
    return socket.emit('event-trigger', true);
  }
  server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    triggerEvent(socket);
  });
```

I also tried to use Module.exports triggerEvent Function and get that function  other pages
My HTML page where I am opening and testing the Socket Connection
test.html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Socket io client</title>
  <script src="http://localhost:3003/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3003");
    // use your socket
    socket.on("event-trigger", (message) => {
      // do something with the message.
      alert(message)
      console.log(message)
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

So currently it works fine. If I open the HTML Page then alert generated by socket server. Also user connected message print on my server console.

Now I have multiple routes and under that multiple files where API functionality is written. So let's say Some routes folder I have handle.js file. Under that file let's say I have an API named as `localhost:3000/likepost`. So on this API when a user like is posted and 200 success response is sent back to Frontend Server, then just after I want to
trigger the event i.e socket .emit('event-trigger', true);  and this event will send Frontend the event fired request, so Frontend will show some notification like `someone liked your post` is rendering on platform something like that.
Please provide me some guidance for that. Any help or suggestion is really appreciated for that.

Answer (score -1):

Your socket connection reference is not attached to the emit function, it should be inside your "connection" (server.on('connection')) callback function 
Reference below :

```
  const io = require('socket.io');
  const server = io.listen(3003);

  server.on('connection', function (socket) {      
    socket.emit('event-trigger', true);      
  });
```

Comment: Earlier I Did this. By the way It works fine. My question is How I generate the event under the api which is written under some folder.

Comment: Dude, you could not pass socket reference with different protocol specification..

Comment: Okay, so what are the efficient way to handle this kind of scenario. Generally, on large Projects, socket connection will create only one time and code is written on some specific file only once. Further on different pages how we can invoke the events.? Kindly Help me out on this. Really appreciated your support.